# The @AfterThrowing advice is not executed

Tags: java, spring-aop

The @AfterThrowing advice is not executed in my program. But other advices are executed.

Here the Aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class RequestFaildAspect {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestFaildAspect.class);
    //match all public method
    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void html() {}

    @Before("html()")
    public void before() {
        logger.error("before");
    }

    @After("html()")
    public void after() {
        logger.error("after");
    }
    /**
     * 处理Page类的html方法抛出的异常RequestFailedException
     */
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "html()", throwing = "ex")
    public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint point, Throwable ex) {
        logger.error("AfterThrowing");
    }
}
```

the exception class

```
package com.jecyhw;
public class Test {
    public void test()  {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = com.jecyhw.SpringAopConfig.class)
public class FjsnwDiseaseTest {

    com.jecyhw.Test test = new com.jecyhw.Test();
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        test.test();
    }
}
```

spring aop configure class

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class SpringAopConfig {
}
```

the @Before and @After advice can execute, only the @AfterThrowing doesn't              execute.

And the spring console output, i found those:

```
13:14:18,381 DEBUG ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory:226 - Found AspectJ method: public void com.jecyhw.request.aspect.RequestFaildAspect.before()
13:14:18,383 DEBUG ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory:226 - Found AspectJ method: public void com.jecyhw.request.aspect.RequestFaildAspect.after()
13:14:18,383 DEBUG ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory:226 - Found AspectJ method: public void com.jecyhw.request.aspect.RequestFaildAspect.afterThrowing(org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint,java.lang.Throwable)
```

the log4j output:

```
2016-08-19 13:14:18  [ main:521 ] - [ ERROR ]  before
2016-08-19 13:14:18  [ main:539 ] - [ ERROR ]  after
```

in log4j's output, AfterThrowing not output.

i set the breakpoint at afterThrowing's method and debug, but not used.

Comment: Read the duplicate or ask yourself what `Test test = new Test();` does and how it's related (or not) to Spring.

Comment: Test test = new Test(); the Test is com.jecyhw.Test class

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, Before and After advice can execute, only the AfterThrowing doesn't execute.

Comment: They aren't executing on the `Test` instance.

Comment: you have to create bean and get Test object from Spring container.

Comment: yes, but i don't know how to modify it. I modify the com.jecyhw.Test to com.jecyhw.Test1, and  @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))") to @Pointcut("execution(* com.jecyhw.Test1.test())"), then all the advice not work. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: @Vaseph, thank you. I add Component annotation on the Test class, then it works.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, thank you, the problem is solved.